# PHP /MySQL Select data from 3 different tables and display result it in one table

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 tables in my database

This is students_absence table

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
| tag_id    | lecture_name  | abs_hours | abs_ratio     | days      |
|-----------+---------------+-----------+---------------+-----------|
| 00000023  | 1             | 8         | 5.3333        | 13/4/2014 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And the 2nd table students

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| tag_id        | name      | collage       | department    | class | gender    |                 |
|---------------+-----------+---------------+---------------+-------+-----------+
| 00000023      | John Deem | Engineering   | Computer      | first | male      |  
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

and the 3rd table lecture_table

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
| id    | lecture_name  | lecturer_name     | start | end   |
|-------+---------------+-------------------+-------+-------+
| 1     | Math 1        | Dr. Anas Ali      | 8     | 10    |
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

So i need to make a query by tag_id(00000023) in students_absence table and get this tag_id and get full information about it from students table. and take the (lecture_name = 1) from students_absence and compare it with (id = 1) in lecture_table and also get full info from it depend on id

the final result should be like this

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| tag_id        | name      | lecture_name  | lecturer_name     | abs_hours     |       
|---------------+-----------+---------------+-------------------+---------------+
| 00000023      | John Deem | Math 1        | Dr. Anas Ali      | 8             |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

i cant get a query give me the above table anyone can advise?

Comment: Dear Abhik Chakraborty i understand you i have changed it to lecture_name to lecture_id and use these query and when i hit search button in my local host browser when i enter 00000023 i get the following error (You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= AND lecture_table.id = ' at line 1)???and i will be highly appreciated to u is can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/join.html)

```
SELECT s.tag_id, s.name, lt.lecture_name, lt.lecturer_name, sa.abs_hours
FROM students_absence sa
JOIN students s ON (s.tag_id = sa.tag_id)
JOIN lecture_table lt ON (s.lecturer_name = lt.id)
WHERE s.tag_id = 00000023;
```

Comment: ok my friend its work finally thank you for your support (echo_Me)and i changed the query to WHERE (sa.tag_id LIKE '%".$query."%')to use it with any tag i entered

Answer (score 0):

(not tested)

```
select s1.tag_id s2.name,s3.lecture_name,s1.abs_hours from students_absence s1 join second_table s2 on s2.tag_id="00000023" and s1.tag_id="00000023" join lecture_table s3 on s1.lecture_name =s3.lecture_name
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that in the 1st table you meant lecture_id rather than lecture_name.
If I understood correctly, the input is  and  and you want to know how many hours a student was missing from a certain class.
Then the query you need goes something like this:

```
SELECT students.tag_id, name, lecture_name, lecturer_name, abs_hours FROM students_absence JOIN students on students_absence.tag_id = students.tag_id JOIN lecture_table on students_absence.lecture_id = lecture_table.id WHERE students.tag_id=<STUDENT_ID> AND lecture_table.id = <LECTURE_ID>
```

If you need a list of all students in all classes just omit the "WHERE" part and everything after that

Answer (score 0):

Try that :

```
SELECT sa.tag_id ,s.name ,lt.lecture_name,lt.lecturer_name,sa.abs_hours 
FROM students_absence sa
INNER JOIN students s ON s.tag_id = sa.tag_id
INNER JOIN lecture_table lt ON lt.id = sa.lecture_name
WHERE sa.tag_id= '00000023'
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL command:

> `SELECT
>       s.tag_id,
>       s.name,
>       l.lecture_name,
>       l.lecturer_name,
>       sa.abs_hours
>   FROM
>       students_absence sa
>       JOIN students s USING (tag_id)
>       JOIN lecture_table l ON (sa.lecture_name = l.id)
>   WHERE
>       sa.tag_id = '00000023'`